# pass the selected option from one form to another in the same html page using Django for backend

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have tow forms. I want to pass selected option from the first form to the other form as a hidden input. How can I do that. I tried the following solution but did not work.

```
<form id="headerform" method="GET" action="{% url 'some url' %}">
    {% if all_p_cities %}
        <select id='pre_sel_city' name="h_qc"  onchange="headerform.submit()">
            {% for city in all_p_cities %}
            {% if city.city_name == post_city %}
            <option value="{{city.city_name}}" selected > {{post_city}}
            </option>

            {% else %}
            <option value="{{city.city_name}}"> {{city.city_name}}
            </option> 

            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    {% else %}
        <select id='pre_sel_city' name="h_qc"  onchange="headerform.submit()">

            <option value="{{post_city}}" selected > {{post_city}}
            </option>

        </select>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

the second form is as follow:

```
<form id='query-box'>
    <!-- predetermined search fields -->
    <input id='sel_city' type="hidden" name="h_qc" value=''>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

I used the javascript to pass the value of first form to the other form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //get the input elements from HTML DOM for preselected input from the main search to customized header search

    var sel_city = document.getElementById("sel_city");

    var pre_sel_city = document.getElementById("pre_sel_city");

    //Get the value of inputs from first form 
    var pre_sel_city_value = pre_sel_city.value;

    //Assign the values of first form to the second
    pre_sel_city.value = pre_sel_city_value;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would post this as a comment since I'm on my phone and can't test it.
You have
    `pre_sel_city.value = pre_sel_city_value;`

Try:

```
//Assign the values of first form to the second
sel_city.value = pre_sel_city_value;
```